# How to enter symbol for inexact differential in xelatex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, xetex

The LaTeX symbol list document recommends this:

```
\def\dbar{{\mathchar’26\mkern-12mu d}}
```

Compiling this gives an error about mathcar being undefined.

A minimal example follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
\def\dbar{{\mathchar’26\mkern-12mu d}}

\author{asd}
\title{asd}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

$\dbar Q = d U + \dbar W$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message changes if I enter the \def in the preamble instead of a different file to "Missing number, treated as zero".

Comment: `\newcommand{\dbar} {\ensuremath{\,\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}` also preserves the space before dbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\dbar{{\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}
\begin{document}
abc $\dbar$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Same error with your snippet: Missing number, treated as zero.

Comment: Make sure that you use the correct apostroph (use the one above the slash key on your keyboard). Or enter the number as decimal instead of octal (`\mathchar22`).

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Copy-paste from the PDF document copied the wrong apostroph.

Comment: Another problem now. Using fontspec, dbar turns into a d. Any ideas?

Comment: Setting option no-math fixed this.

Comment: Check the kerning.

Comment: @egreg ? did something change?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, it has been wrong from the beginning: character `'26` is only 9mu wide

Comment: @egreg But -9mu looks wrong.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, of course; the `d` is 12mu wide. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253108/4427

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention `xelatex` in your question I assume that you want a unicode-type solution to your problem.

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
đ $\text{đ}$
\end{document}
```