# d with a little line through the top of it

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In math mode one can do `$\hbar$`, which produces an `h` with a little line through the top of it. I want to do the same thing, except with the letter `d` instead. Is there a generalization of `$\hbar$` that works for other letters besides just `h`?

Comment: `\dj{}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: the 'fontenc' package doesn't seem to work with the 'amsart' document class

Comment: No! No problem. They work very well.

Comment: I'm using the package, but it's still telling me that \dj is an invalid command in math mode

Comment: Hum, you want to use it in math mode!

Comment: I was using it in math mode, hum

Comment: @Sigur and Rohan. `\dj{}` is a text-mode symbol. In math it would be `$\text{\dj}$`. You should load the package `lmodern` as well in order to get that symbol unpixeld.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way that works with both pdflatex and mathjax?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create a specific *command* `\dbar` for this purpose.

```
\newcommand{\dbar}{d\hspace*{-0.08em}\bar{}\hspace*{0.1em}}
```

### Full Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\dbar}{d\hspace*{-0.08em}\bar{}\hspace*{0.1em}}
\begin{document}
$\hbar$, $\dbar$.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Comment: A more convenient command could be `\mathchar '26 \mkern-11mu d`. This is the same idea used in `\hbar`.

Comment: @Sigur I think better with `-12mu`.

Comment: @skpblack, I was talking about the char and kern. OK.

Comment: Also, in general, kerns are better than `\hspace`s for things like this, because `\hspace` has stretchable glue in it, whereas a `\kern` or `\mkern` does not.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes i use `\hspace*` that avoids this problem.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I'm afraid that both you and skpblack are wrong: `\hspace{...}` becomes stretchable *only* if the argument contains stretch components, so `\hspace{2pt}` will never stretch. The `\hspace*` variant has nothing to do with stretching or shrinking *per se*, because it obeys the same rules as the normal command. The main difference between a skip (`\hspace`) and a kern is that the latter isn't considered a line break point.

Answer (score 15):

There is code in the Comprehensive List of Symbols, but it's wrong: what's suggested is

```
\newcommand{\dbar}{{\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}
```

but one needs to compensate the amount of backup, which is larger than the width of the bar by 3mu:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dbar}{{\mkern3mu\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}

\begin{document}

$32\lambda^2 \dbar_w$

$32\lambda^2 d_w$

$32\lambda^2 \hat{d}_w$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact that the width is 9mu is confirmed by the definition of `\hbar` in Plain TeX:

```
\hbar:
macro:->{\mathchar '26\mkern -9muh}
```

Of course, different math fonts may need different amounts of spacing.

A possibly better definition is

```
\newcommand{\dbar}{{d\mkern-7mu\mathchar'26\mkern-2mu}}
```

so that the bar doesn't protrude as much on the right:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dbar}{{d\mkern-7mu\mathchar'26\mkern-2mu}}

\begin{document}

$d\dbar d$

$h\hbar h$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**For PDFLaTeX**:

As recommended by Sigur. You should load the package `lmodern` as well as the output will be pixeled with out it.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
in text \dj{} and math $\textit{\dj}$   
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**For Lua- or XeLaTeX**:

The output is the same as above. You can use the unicode [U+0111](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0111/index.htm) or copy paste that symbol directly into your code.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
in text \symbol{"0111}  and math $\textit{\symbol{"0111}}$
\end{document}
```

The package `unicode-math` does not contain this symbol yet. It just contains the unicode [U+00F0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0/index.htm) with the command `$\matheth$` which could be an alternative.

You can find fonts that support that symbol on your system by clicking [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%C4%91%20-%20LATIN%20SMALL%20LETTER%20D%20WITH%20STROKE%20%28U%2B0111%29). Here are some font examples. Choose one and write your macro like `\newcommand*{\dbar}{{\fontspec{font_of_your_choice}\symbol{"0111}}}`.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        Font & Example\\\midrule
        Latin Modern & \symbol{"0111}\\
        Code2000 & \setmainfont{Code2000.ttf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        Comic Sans MS & \setmainfont{comic.ttf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        Consolas & \setmainfont{consola.ttf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        DejaVu Sans & \setmainfont{DejaVuSans.ttf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        EB Garamond & \setmainfont{EB Garamond}\symbol{"0111}\\
        Linux Libertine &\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}\symbol{"0111}\\
        Quivira &\setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        XITS &\setmainfont{xits-regular.otf}\symbol{"0111}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: using `\textit` in math mode feels rather wrong to me. And if it is left out the first example gives `LaTeX Warning: Command \dj invalid in math mode on input line 8.`

Comment: @clemens Yes of course this was a tweak. The command `\dj` is a textcommand. and therefore I used `\textit` here.