# Syntax for in-complete differential

Tags: syntax

I am looking for the syntax of the `$d$` with the apostrophe, as in the picture.
[image]

I tried at [wiki's help page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula) but wouldn't find.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean the "crossed d": đ? Also known as "d with stroke"? *Generally* you should try [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or one of the alternative suggestions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character). However, admittedly, they probably wouldn't have helped you this time, you need the answer below

Comment: I'd use `\delta` as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laws_of_thermodynamics) and *every* textbook I know of does.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I remember to have seen this symbol in Thermodynamics being used in older textbooks, Landau , I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in  *The LaTeX Comprehensive Symbol List*. Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
\def\dbar{{\mkern3mu\mathchar'26\mkern-12mu d}}

\begin{document}

 \[ dU = \underbrace{\dbar Q}_\text{Heat} \mskip6mu + \mskip6mu\underbrace{\dbar W\vphantom{Q}}_\text{\clap{Mech.\,Works}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you see the wrong spacing?

Comment: @egreg: Not really. For the `+` sign?

Comment: Look closely at the placement of “dQ” with respect to the underbrace. Every usage of `\dbar` contributes 3mu of negative space.

Comment: Oh! Yes. I didn't even think of checking that.  Thank you the tip, I've corrected the code. How comes it's -3mu? Is it linked to the fact that for `\hbar` one uses `mkern -9mu`instead of `-12mu`?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253108/4427 (same code provided some months ago).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether there is a symbol already like that, but I stole the definition of `\hbar` and changed it al little bit.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dbar}{{\mathchar '26\mkern -11.5mud}}

\begin{document}
$d U = \dbar Q + \dbar W$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is in text mode, with T1 font encoding (`\dj`). `TIPA` also has the character. But Detexify couldn't find me a math mode version

Comment: @Au101: Thanks, I did not know that.

Comment: And where's the spacing left of the crossed d?

Answer (score 5):

The definition proposed in the Comprehensive list is completely wrong, I'm afraid.

The proposed definition is

```
\def\dbar{{\mathchar’26\mkern-12mu d}}
```

but this applies too wide a backspace, considering that 9mu is the width of the bar.

Here's a possibly better one that doesn't suffer from the backspacing problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dbar}{{d\mkern-7mu\mathchar'26\mkern-2mu}}

\begin{document}

$d\dbar d$

$h\hbar h$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For your particular application you need a couple of tricks more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dbar}{{d\mkern-7mu\mathchar'26\mkern-2mu}}

\begin{document}

\[
dU = \underbrace{\dbar Q}_{\scriptscriptstyle\text{Heat}} +
     \underbrace{\dbar W\vphantom{Q}}_{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\hspace{-1.5em}Mech.\,Work\hspace{-1.5em}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found at page 210 of [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) that *barred d* can be achieved as:

```
\def\dbar{{\mathchar '26\mkern-12mu d}}
```

Indeed one way to sketch the equation above is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\dbar{{\mathchar '26\mkern-12mu d}}

\begin{document}
\[
d U = \underbrace{\dbar Q}_{\text{Heat}} + \underbrace{\dbar W}_{\text{Mech. Work}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I know it's wrong in the question, but you should really use `\text{Heat}` (and the same for Work, obviously) - or, if italics is desired, `\mathit{Heat}`, in order to achieve the correct spacing. Generally words should be set as text and upright, but italics may be desired for whatever reason (`\textit{}` may be preferable for italics, actually). This will also give a proper space in Mech. Work, although if in text mode, you'll need `Mech.\ Work` otherwise you'll get a sentence-ending space

Comment: I assume you're not loading `amsmath`? `\text{}` is only defined in `amsmath`, otherwise it's good old `\mathrm{}`, `\textrm{}` or - the old standby that was generally preferred - `\mbox{}`. *Probably* could've done with mentioning that in my comment, to be fair :)

Comment: @Au101 Indeed I wasn't... Thank you again for the improvements! (I didn't want to cheat over an upvoted answer...despite the other answers are far more accurate and this thing in particular is a bit "off topic" as - I think - the question was more focused on the "dbar" fact) Anyway, great ;)