# Exact positioning of superimposed symbols

Tags: stacking-symbols, combine

I would like to have an equality sign with a dot right in the middle, between the bars. After reading this answer:

[How do you superimpose two symbols over each other?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21644/how-do-you-superimpose-two-symbols-over-each-other)

I tried to use `\mathrlap{=}\cdot`, `\mathclap{=}\cdot` and `\superimpose{=}{\cdot}`, but each time the dot is either too far left or right. Is there a way to control the exact position of the dot so I can put it in the middle?

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax for `\superimpose`. But see the revamped answer, particularly the second part.

Comment: What is the meaning of this symbol?

Comment: @projetmbc It's new. I want to use it as a placeholder that indicates that it goes from a 2-categorical structure to a 0-categorical one. Indicate the categorical level of the domain and codomain by the number of lines horizontally and vertically, with the 0-categorical case being represented by a point. This way, the notation can be generalized to arbitrary n-categories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\ooalign` for this purpose. Using `\mathpallette` will allow proper spacing for subscripts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\equaldot}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\eqd@t\relax}}
\newcommand{\eqd@t}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1=$\cr
    \hidewidth$\m@th#1\cdot$\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$A\equaldot B_{A\equaldot B_{A\equaldot B}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I copied your code, but it gives me a error "command already defined" error, though the word is never used before and only in the document later. And in the document, the dot is below the equality sign. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: @AlexanderPraehauser: You are probably loading a package that has `\eqdot` already defined, such as `fdsymbol` or `stix` or `MnSymbol`. Try changing the command name to `\equaldot` or something of your choice. I edited my answer with this change. In the future you should provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282196/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\eq}{\mathrel{{=}\mkern-9.5mu{\cdot}\mkern4mu}}
\begin{document}
$a\eq b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since this symbol will presumably be used as a relation, you should enclose `=\mkern-14.5mu\cdot \mkern4mu` with `\mathrel{...}`. Note that the spacing will not be correct for subscripts. For example, try `$a\eq b_{a\eq b}$`

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathpalette\superimpose{{=}{\cdot}}$
\end{document}
```

the dot seems to by placed absolutely correct. However, you can use, e.g., `\mskip` to move the dot left or right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\superimpose}[2]{%
  {\ooalign{$#1\@firstoftwo#2$\cr\hfil$#1\@secondoftwo#2$\hfil\cr}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathpalette\superimpose{{=}{\cdot}}$

$\mathpalette\superimpose{{=}{\mskip5mu\cdot}}$

$\mathpalette\superimpose{{=}{\mskip-5mu\cdot}}$

\end{document}
```