# How can I write this symbol in latex?

Tags: fonts, symbols

How can I write letter d with hyphen in the image file?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203508/121799) and its answers. (And judging from your profile picture I could imagine you'd also enjoy [this brand new package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in the smaller math styles, let me know.  This only works in display/text-styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\stroked{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine
  {3.2pt}{d}{\mkern5.4mu\mbox{-}}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}
\begin{document}
\stroked
\end{document}
```

[image]