# Subindex before the integral

Tags: equations, integral

Someone knows how to display a subindex before the integral? The image shows an example, the subindex I and R it's what I'm looking for to display in Latex.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `amsmath` package (which should be always loaded if you type more math than `1+1=2`) provides the `\sideset` macro to add indices to the left of large operators like `\sum`, `\prod`, and (abusing it a little) `\int`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\sideset{_I}{}\oint \frac{d Q}{T}
= \sideset{_I}{_ i^f}\int \frac{d Q}{T}
  + \sideset{_R}{_i^f}\int\frac{d Q}{T}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath}
```

uses a Times-like font closer to the picture you posted

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use also `leftidx` package....and for the `đ` here there is a possible link: [d with a little line through the top of it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203508/d-with-a-little-line-through-the-top-of-it)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{leftidx}


\begin{document}
\[\leftidx{_I}{\oint} \frac{dQ}{T}
= \leftidx{_I}{\int_i^f} \frac{dQ}{T}
  + \leftidx{_R}{\int_i^f}\frac{dQ}{T}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]