# Why does making a d with a bar through it not behave like an h with a bar through it?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, unicode-math, math-fonts

This is a follow-up to my previous question [How can I get an upright \hbar using unicode-math?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/612258/218142). I am experimenting with making a `d` with a bar through it like one would use in physics to denote an inexact differential (see also [How to enter symbol for inexact differential in xelatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24037/218142) and [How can I call unicode characters in LaTeX or LyX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/313006/218142) and [d with a little line through the top of it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203508/218142)). I see the bar on the `d` glyph seems to shift relative to the letter whereas I don't see that behavior with the `h` character. Is this behavior real and, if so, what causes it? Does it vary with different fonts? Can it be overcome?

Experimenting with the values of `\mkern` did not make the shift go away.

Here is my MWE:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\hbar}{{\mathpalette\hbar@\relax\symup{h}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\hbar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.07\height}{\(\m@th#1\mkern-2mu\mathchar"AF\)}}%
}
\makeatother
% Let's try a \dbar glyph for inexact differentials.
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\dbar}{{\mathpalette\dbar@{\relax}{\symsfup{d}}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\dbar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{-0.09\height}{\(\m@th#1\mkern+3mu\mathchar"AF\)}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\( \hbar \scriptstyle\hbar \scriptscriptstyle\hbar \)

\( \dbar \scriptstyle\dbar \scriptscriptstyle\dbar \)
\end{document}
```

Here is the MWE output:

[image: Output showing the difference between hbar and dbar]

**UPDATE:** After much experimentation, the following seems to work but I can't completely explain why. If I change `[c]` to `[r]` I notice that the bar doesn't move regardless of what I provide for `\mkern`.

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\dbar}{{\symsfup{d}\mathpalette\dbar@\relax\relax}}%
}
\newcommand*{\dbar@}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][c]{\raisebox{-0.07\height}{\(\m@th#1\mkern-6mu\mathchar"AF\)}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: On the 'd', the bars are all the same length, independent of the font size.

Comment: for h the bar is placed first in a zero width box sticking out on teh right but for d you want to place the bar after in a zero width box sticking out on the left,

Comment: or as for h bar, you could use U+0111 đ

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I knew about that, but in this case I really want a sans d and a bold sans variant (I didn't include those in the MWE).

Comment: bold and sans like this? `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\Large^^^^0111 \textsf{^^^^0111} \textsf{\textbf{^^^^0111}} \textbf{^^^^0111}\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `unicode-math`, your best option is to insert đ (U+0111, Latin small letter d with stroke) from a text font that supports it.  If your main font does not, you can use `\setmathrm` or `\setmathsf` to change your `\mathrm` or `\mathsf` alphabet to one that does, or define a new math alphabet that does with `\setmathfontface`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % Or your font package of choice.

\newcommand\dbar{\mathsf{đ}}
\newcommand\vardbar{\text{\sffamily\ulcshape\upshape đ}}
\newcommand\mitdbar{\text{\sffamily\ulcshape\slshape đ}}

\begin{document}
\[ \dbar \vardbar \mitdbar
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Sample]

The `\text` commands I use are somewhat complicated, because they leave the weight unchanged but set every other axis, but you can probably get away with `\textnormal{đ}`

If you are compiling with legacy TeX instead, you can technically use the same approach there too, because the 8-bit T3 encoding supports this character.  You can select a font family (Computer Modern Roman, Computer Modern Sans Serif, Times, Helvetica, Junicode or Linguistics Pro), and some of these support slanted shapes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage[T3,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textdbar}{T3}{"A1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textdbar}{T3}
\newcommand\dbar{\textnormal{\textdbar}}
\newcommand\vardbar{\textnormal{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont\textdbar}}
\newcommand\mitdbar{\textnormal{\fontfamily{cmss}\slshape\selectfont\textdbar}}

\begin{document}
\[ \dbar\vardbar\mitdbar
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Tipa sample]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way with stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\newcommand\dbar{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.7\LMpt}{\SavedStyle\mathsf{d}}{\SavedStyle\bar{}%
  \mkern2.25mu}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
\( \dbar \scriptstyle\dbar \scriptscriptstyle\dbar \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the `\mathsf` to, for example, `\mathit`, results in

[image]

The horizontal placement of the bar can be changed by tweaking the `2.25mu`.  The vertical placement by adjusting the `-.7\LMpt`.